# Jstl в чем смысл form:lable атрибута path?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

Для чего нужен атрибут path y form:lable. При такой записи все нормально выводится:

```
<form:lable> Publisher </form:lable>
```

Но к чему вот такая запись, какой смысл в path. На что влияет этот атрибут:

```
<form:lable path=publisher> Publisher </form:lable>
```

Например, при использовании

```
<form:input path=publisher/>
```

в атрибуте path указывается переменная куда в будет сохраняться значение.

Comment: Переменная описывает путь сохранения, туда куда записывается значение.

Comment: Переменная описывает путь сохранения, туда куда записывается значение.

Comment: это в <form:input>...</form:input> так. A <form:lable path=publisher>...</form:lable>, что записывает, то что указываем в теле? Это же вроде для вывода на форму. Я в path указывал несуществующие имена и ничего не менялось, просто выводится то, что указано в теле тега. Я подозреваю, что path биндит имеющуюся переменную, с тем, что мы указываем в теле тега, если это так, то для чего? И почему можно указать абракадабру?

Comment: Куда биндит и какую переменную?

Comment: <form:input path=publisher/> так если бы я знал наверняка, я бы не задавал вопрос. Я не знаю что делает path в form:lable.

Comment: Для начала нужно показать что получается когда используешь form:lable

Comment: Выводится то, что внутри тега напишешь

Comment: Значит переменная видна только внутри тэга